# How to access Files in Google Cloud Storage through GKE pods

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, axios, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying get image files of Google Cloud Storage (GCS) in my Node.js application using Axios client. On develop mode using my PC I pass a Bearer Token and all works properly.

But, I need to use this in production in a cluster hosted on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE).

I made recommended tuturials to create a service account (GSA), then I vinculed with kubernetes account (KSA), via Workload identity approach, but when I try get files througt one endpoint on my app, I'm receiving:

```
{"statusCode":401,"message":"Unauthorized"}
```

What is missing to make?

---

### Update: What I've done:

1. Create Google Service Account

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts

2. Create Kubernetes Service Account

```
# gke-access-gcs.ksa.yaml file

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: gke-access-gcs
```

```
kubectl apply -f gke-access-gcs.ksa.yaml
```

3. Relate KSAs and GSAs

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
  --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
  --member "serviceAccount:cluster_project.svc.id.goog[k8s_namespace/ksa_name]" \
  gsa_name@gsa_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

4. Note the KSA and complete the link between KSA and GSA

```
kubectl annotate serviceaccount \
  --namespace k8s_namespace \
   ksa_name \
   iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=gsa_name@gsa_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

5. Set Read and Write role:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding project-id \
--member=serviceAccount:gsa-account@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/storage.objectAdmin
```

6. Test access:

```
kubectl run -it \
  --image google/cloud-sdk:slim \
  --serviceaccount ksa-name \
  --namespace k8s-namespace \
  workload-identity-test
```

The above command works correctly. Note that was passed `--serviceaccount` and `workload-identity`. Is this necessary to GKE?

PS: I don't know if this influences, but I am using SQL Cloud with proxy in the project.

Comment: You will need to be authorised to access the files in your Cloud Storage, unless they are publicly available. Previously, you would create a service account and download as json which you can include in a Kubernetes secret (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform#kubectl) but the recommended approach is currently Workload identity https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity

Comment: Don't use service account key file if you are on GKE, use workload identity!

Comment: In addition, where is the unauthorized permission? Inside your pod? Or to reach your pod?

Comment: I'm using workload identity approach. The Unnauthorized permission message is displayed when I access one endpoint that uses Axios (trying to get an image from GCS)

Comment: Have you used the guide provided by user keni?  Could you tell which guide/tutorial/site were you following to get to this point?  Could you provide the steps you followed otherwise?

Comment: keni, guillaume-blaquiere and dawid-kruk I include in the post description the steps I have already taken. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I ran the setup you've shown here (configuration part looks like: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity). I ran simple nodejs "app" (https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/uploadFile.js) and was successful in connecting with gcp buckets. Could you share the sample of code you tried to connect with gcp buckets? Do you have workload identity enabled on the cluster? As for second to last sentence. It's important to have the `--serviceAccount`, the `workload-identity-test` is only a name for the pod.

Comment: @btd1337 please take a look on the update I made to the answer. It explains why you weren't able to use Workload Identity with the axios client.

Comment: @btd1337 did you check Dawid's answer? Does it solve your issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### EDIT

Issue portrayed in the question is related to the fact that axios client **does not use** the Application Default Credentials (as official Google libraries) mechanism that [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) takes advantage of.  The ADC checks:

> - If the environment variable  `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`  is set, ADC uses the service account file that the variable points to.
> - If the environment variable  `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`  isn't set, ADC uses the default service account that Compute Engine, Google Kubernetes Engine, App Engine, Cloud Run, and Cloud Functions provide.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Authentication: Production](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-nodejs)*

**This means that axios client will need to fall back to the `Bearer token` authentication method to authenticate against Google Cloud Storage.**

The authentication with `Bearer token` is described in the official documentation as following:

> #### API authentication
>
> To make requests using OAuth 2.0 to either the Cloud Storage  [XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/overview)  or  [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1), include your application's access token in the  `Authorization`  header in every request that requires authentication. You can generate an access token from the  [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).
>
> ```
> Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN
> ```
>
> The following is an example of a request that lists objects in a bucket.
>
> > [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#json-api)
> >
> > Use the  [list](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list)  method of the Objects resource.
> >
> > ```
> > GET /storage/v1/b/example-bucket/o HTTP/1.1
> > Host: www.googleapis.com
> > Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHES6ZRVmB7fkLtd1XTmq6mo0S1wqZZi3-Lh_s-6Uw7p8vtgSwg
> > ```
>
> -- [Cloud.google.com: Storage: Docs: Api authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#apiauth)

---

I've included **basic example** of a code snippet using Axios to query the Cloud Storage (requires `$ npm install axios`):

```js
const Axios = require('axios');

const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ${OAUTH2_TOKEN}' }
};

Axios.get( 
  'https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET-NAME/o/',
  config
).then(
  (response) => {
    console.log(response.data.items);
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log('Oh no. Something went wrong :(');
    // console.log(err) <-- Get the full output!
  }
);
```

I left below example of Workload Identity setup with a node.js official library code snippet as it could be useful to other community members.

---

Posting this answer as I've managed to use `Workload Identity` and a simple `nodejs` app to send and retrieve data from `GCP bucket`.

I included some bullet points for troubleshooting potential issues.

---

### Steps:

- Check if `GKE` cluster has `Workload Identity` enabled.
- Check if your `Kubernetes service account` is associated with your `Google Service account`.
- Check if example workload is using correct `Google Service account` when connecting to the API's.
- Check if your `Google Service account` is having correct permissions to access your `bucket`.

You can also follow the official documentation:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity)*

---

Assuming that:

- Project (ID) named: `awesome-project` <- **it's only example**
- Kubernetes namespace named: `bucket-namespace`
- Kubernetes service account named: `bucket-service-account`
- Google service account named: `google-bucket-service-account`
- Cloud storage bucket named: `workload-bucket-example` <- **it's only example**

I've included the commands:

```sh
$ kubectl create namespace bucket-namespace
$ kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace bucket-namespace bucket-service-account
$ gcloud iam service-accounts create google-bucket-service-account
$ gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser --member "serviceAccount:awesome-project.svc.id.goog[bucket-namespace/bucket-service-account]" google-bucket-service-account@awesome-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
$ kubectl annotate serviceaccount --namespace bucket-namespace bucket-service-account iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=google-bucket-service-account@awesome-project-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Using the guide linked above check the service account authenticating to API's:

- `$ kubectl run -it --image google/cloud-sdk:slim --serviceaccount bucket-service-account --namespace bucket-namespace workload-identity-test`

The output of `$ gcloud auth list` should show:

```sh
                           Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       google-bucket-service-account@AWESOME-PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

> Google service account created earlier should be present in the output!

Also it's required to add the permissions for the service account to the bucket. You can either:

- Use `Cloud Console`
- Run: `$ gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:google-bucket-service-account@awesome-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com:roles/storage.admin gs://workload-bucket-example`

To download the file from the `workload-bucket-example` following code can be used:

```js
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC

/**
 * This application demonstrates how to perform basic operations on files with
 * the Google Cloud Storage API.
 *
 * For more information, see the README.md under /storage and the documentation
 * at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs.
 */
const path = require('path');
const cwd = path.join(__dirname, '..');

function main(
  bucketName = 'workload-bucket-example',
  srcFilename = 'hello.txt',
  destFilename = path.join(cwd, 'hello.txt')
) {
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage();

  async function downloadFile() {
    const options = {
      // The path to which the file should be downloaded, e.g. "./file.txt"
      destination: destFilename,
    };

    // Downloads the file
    await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(srcFilename).download(options);

    console.log(
      `gs://${bucketName}/${srcFilename} downloaded to ${destFilename}.`
    );
  }

  downloadFile().catch(console.error);
  // [END storage_download_file]
}
main(...process.argv.slice(2));
```

The code is exact copy from:

- *[Googleapis.dev: NodeJS: Storage](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/)*
- *[Github.com: Googleapis: Nodejs-storage: downloadFile.js](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/downloadFile.js)*

Running this code should produce an output:

```sh
root@ubuntu:/# nodejs app.js 
gs://workload-bucket-example/hello.txt downloaded to /hello.txt.
```

```sh
root@ubuntu:/# cat hello.txt 
Hello there!
```