# Update the kubernetes configMap data from pod

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, configmap

I have a cronjob object that creates a pod once every day. After processing some records in the pod I want the pod to store a timestamp that will be picked up the next day as input.

Therefore, I need some way to store some data from a pod that can be consumed later by another pod in the same cluster. I don't want to use the Persistent volumes for some reason. Therefore, is there any other approach for this.

I am considering using configMap for this. But I am not able to confirm if we can write or update data of a configMap from a pod.

After searching for it I found this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62099) that says configMaps are meant to be readonly at least till April, 2018 when this issue was created. I am wondering if any workaround has come since then.

Comment: A possible approach to update configmap inside pod without restart is mounting it’s content as volume.

Comment: You don't say where the records actually are, but can you put this information somewhere like a database table or a file, using storage you already have?

Comment: (You _could_ use the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) to rewrite the ConfigMap or otherwise store the data in a resource, but you'd be writing Kubernetes-specific code that will be a little tricky to run in other environments, and there are specific in-cluster permission settings that are required.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I would avoid the use of Kubernetes API to rewrite the configMap as I want the solution for multiple environments which may fail with this approach.

Comment: Yes, storing the information in the database is one option but for my scenario, the table will always have one row. Therefore, I was trying to avoid it.

Comment: @RahulSatal GCS can be considered as one more option. With the proper [permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63664800/how-to-access-files-in-google-cloud-storage-through-gke-pods), you should be able to call an object from any pod. If not already done, you can additionally review [storage options](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/storage-overview#managed_options) to plan storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use kubectl to modify an annotation of the `CronJob` object in case the value is safe to share as plane text. In this case just permission to kubectl annotate would be needed,

To write:

```
kubectl annotate cronjob your-cronjob your-annotation='value'
```

To read:

```
kubectl get cronjob your-cronjob -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations.your-annotation}'
```

Also, to avoid reading you could also pass the annotation value as an `ENV` variable:

```
      env:
    - name: MYVARIABLE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.annotations.your-annotation
```

Comment: Yes, the value is safe to share as plain text. I doubt that with this solution I would be able to write back the annotation from inside a pod ?

Comment: Yes you can, the only thing is missing is a service account with the binds for the correct permissions, do you need me to add the example?

Comment: Yes, please add the example.